# Change python installation directory arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, python-2.7

I've recently installed arcgis 10.2 on C: of my machine, I did this while my external HDD was plugged into E:, and the installer put python onto the E: Why it would do this I have no idea. Now I can't do anything in ArcPy or toolbox unless I have the HDD plugged in. Am I able to move this python27 installation and then tell arcgis where I have moved it to, or do I need to re-install (without my HDD plugged in)?

Comment: Yes, go back to your install disc and install it from there. There are specific libs that need to be installed with Python so it is best to let the installer do it. You should uninstall the existing python first.

Comment: To keep it simple and especially if ArcGIS and ArcPy are critical to your work I would uninstall both Desktop and Python, then reinstall taking care that they go where you want them to.

Comment: Agreed. Best to remove everything and start again as @PolyGeo said, make sure you uninstall the python on the external drive though. You might be able to get away with a *repair* install if you're not keen on uninstall/reinstall of everything.

Comment: A nice bonus from being a long-time ArcGIS user is that you learn to rebuild a Windows machine really quickly ;)

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS 10.1 installed ArcTutor and Python27 on my G: drive. I moved the folders to C:\ArcGIS\ArcTutor and C:\Python27. Doing this broke ArcMap; it attempts to start, but just closes without errors. 
Instead of uninstalling/reinstalling, I started editing the registry, but there were way too many keys to update manually (regedit does not have search and replace!). I didn't back up the registry first, which i should have done, but luckily the following worked...
I found a free registry editor (regedt33.exe) that has search and replace from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/regedt33/files/latest/download 
I used this to change anything with G:\ArcTutor and anything with G:\ArcGIS to the C: drive. There were hundreds, and thousands of changes. After the changes, I launched ArcMap and it seems to be working ok.